# Two subclasses inherit properties of superclass and doesn't lost the scope

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

For help you help me i'm going to illustrate the problem with an example:

```
var SuperClass = function() {
  this.propertieOfSuperClass = 'A';

  this.init();
};

SuperClass.prototype.init = function() {
 console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // ouput 'A';
};
```

```
// Some code here to do the magic for SubClass1
// Some code here to do the magic for SubClass2
```

SubClass1:

```
var SubClass1 = function() {
  this.methodOfSubClass1();
};

SubClass1.prototype.methodOfSubClass1 = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};
```

SubClass2:

```
var SubClass2 = function() {
  this.methodOfSubClass2();
};

SubClass2.prototype.methodOfSubClass = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};
```

I want be able to have this SuperClass which i set the properties and other two subclasses which i can access the properties of SuperClass, but without lose the scope.

I was trying to use inside of my SuperClass init method:

```
SubClass1.call(this);
SubClass2.call(this);
```

And this will make the properties of `SuperClass` accessible, but the SubClass's will lost their scope, so i cant call `methodOfSubClass1` and `methodOfSubClass2`, because they doesn't exist in the `SuperClass`.

How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var SuperClass = function() {
  this.propertieOfSuperClass = 'A';
  this.init();
};

SuperClass.prototype.init = function() {
 console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // ouput 'A';
};

var SubClass1 = function() {
  SuperClass.call(this); // Call parent constructor
  this.methodOfSubClass1();
};
SubClass1.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype); // Inheritance

SubClass1.prototype.methodOfSubClass1 = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};

var SubClass2 = function() {
  SuperClass.call(this); // Call parent constructor
  this.methodOfSubClass2();
};
SubClass2.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype); // Inheritance

SubClass2.prototype.methodOfSubClass2 = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};
```

Comment: Just realize in your code exmaple, 'A' will be logged twice for each subclass as both the parent's init method as well as their individual methods are called.

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Simple do:

```
var SuperClass = function SuperClass() {
  this.propertieOfSuperClass = 'A';

  this.init();
};

SuperClass.prototype.init = function() {
 console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // ouput 'A';

 SubClass.call(this);
};
```

Them:

```
SuperClass.prototype = Object.create(SubClass.prototype);
```

Them in the SubClass:

```
var SubClass = function() {
  console.log(this); // output will be the SuperClass

  this.methodOfSubClass();
};
```

The important part is now:

```
SubClass.prototype.constructor = SubClass;

SubClass1.prototype.methodOfSubClass = function() {
  console.log(this.propertieOfSuperClass); // output 'A';
};
```

You can do the same with SubClass2.